# Can't use physical iOS device (iPod Touch), even if above deployment target iOS version for .NET MAUI app

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, maui, deployment-target

I have an issue where I am trying to use my iPod touch in to debug my .NET MAUI code.
I plug my iPod into my Macbook and under Debug (where I set the devices)
I get that my device OS version is lower than my deployment target.  My iPod is version 15.7 and I'm using Xcode 14.2 for my .NET MAUI project:

[image]

The project is a new "HelloWorld" .NET 7 MAUI project.

I then open up my Project properties and under target platforms->iOS targets I change the Target iOS version from 16.1 to 15.4:

[image]

I can build and run for MacCatalyst but when I try to build and run for any of my iOS simulators (running iOS 16.2) my app crashed:

InnerException:

```
    InnerException  {System.MissingFieldException: Field not found: Microsoft.Maui.IPropertyMapper`2<Microsoft.Maui.IShapeView, Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.IShapeViewHandler> Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ShapeViewHandler.Mapper Due to: Could not find field in class}   System.MissingFieldException
```

with Message:

```
"The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Shapes.Shape' threw an exception."   string
```

[image]

and the debug section still says my device OS version is lower than deployment target.

If I create a new HelloWorld project using .NET 6 instead of 7 I can change the deployment target for iOS to 15.4 and my project builds and runs on my iOS simulator (running iOS version 16.2) without crashing but I can't use my iPod for debugging (greyed out) as the iPod shows up as unsupported device as shown in image above .

Why can't I use my iPod touch running iOS 15.73 even after reducing the target iOS version to 15.4?
(Also a bonus help would be why is my iphone simulator crashing for .Net 7 MAUI project)

Can someone help me figure this out?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Run Xcode. Is iPod touch found? If so, use Xcode to download device provisioning. Restart VS, reconnect iPod. Hopefully will recognize it now.